# How to get a random value from a random WebElement from a List of WebElements

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I am trying to save in a string the value from a random attribute
After that,I want to click on it so I can save the title of the page and compare the two strings
My code is right here:

```
public void clickOnRandomProduct(List <WebElement> elements){


        Random r = new Random();
        int randomValue = r.nextInt(elements.size()); 
        String valoareField=elements.get(randomValue).getAttribute("alt");
        System.out.println(valoareField);
        elements.get(randomValue).click();

    }
```

I receive "null" from my string and I don't know why

Comment: You don't show the code where you're assigning the values to the list of elements, but I'm guessing they're all images since you both mean to check for the "alt" attribute and to click on them?  Are you limiting your array to only one type (tag) of element?

Comment: Yeah
It's a page that contains products with images
I want to get the attribute value "alt" from a random product
Then I want to click on that product
Then I want to get the text from the product and compare the strings

Comment: Are you using "//img" as the xpath?  Are you checking for an empty list?  Can you post a segment of the HTML code in your original message?

Comment: This is the path of a random product displayed on the page

<img src="https://s0emagst.akamaized.net/products/9650/9649839/images/res_976546cfeabc006e02878ea59be73af4_200x200_fbdc.jpg" alt="Sistem Desktop PC All-in-One Acer DQ.UAPEX.002 cu procesor AMD E1 7010 1.5 GHz, 19.5”, 4GB, 1TB, Intel HD Graphics, Microsoft Windows 10 Home, Black, Mouse + Tastatura"/>

I want to get the text from the alt attribute in valoareField String

Comment: It's possible that it's returning null on this one particular example because the code appears to have a flaw: It uses a double quote to note inches, I assume screen size (19.5"), which causes it confusion when parsing the text.  Otherwise I see nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: If I change the code for a single WebElement I receive the value that I want for the element
If I let it from a list of WebElements I receive only null values
Can you help me please with that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I figured out your problem below.  If so, please accept it as the answer so I can get credit.  Thanks.

Comment: After you get the elements list, loop through that list and print every `alt`... do you get anything? My guess is that your list is not the elements you are expecting. Post a link to the page and the code that you are using to scrape the elements list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I didn't spot this earlier.

Change your function declaration:

```
public void clickOnRandomProduct(List<WebELement> elements) {
```

And of course, change the code where you are declaring/setting that list.

Comment: I changed the declaration of the function like this:

public void clickOnRandomProduct(List<WebElement> elements){

     //construiesc pe langa validare de titlu
     Random r = new Random();
        int randomValue = r.nextInt(elements.size()); 
        String valoareField=elements.get(randomValue).getAttribute("alt");
        System.out.println(valoareField);
        elements.get(randomValue).click();
         
    }

but I still get the null value form the webelement

Comment: If, as you stated, the logic works with a single web element but not with the array, then the problem must lie in your array (list).  Did you change the declaration of the elements list itself in the calling portion of the code?  What is the line of code where you define and initialize the elements list?  It should be something like `List<WebElements> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img"));`

Comment: List<WebElement> selectRandomProduct=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='thumbnail js-product-url']"));

This is what I've declared my list of WebElement
The xpath is ok,on the page I have 60 elements that have this value for attribute class and the xpath gives me 60 results match
So the problem isn't with my xpath

Comment: At this point, I can only echo what @JeffC said.  Without seeing the HTML code, we can't be certain that the list is what you think it might be, or that there are ALT tags for each item.  For that matter, even that it's operating in a true random manner.  You should probably step through the code with a debugger and examine the values.